# HaProxy to Tomcat over SSL

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, tomcat, haproxy

I am trying to configure HaProxy - Tomcat communication over HTTPS. That is, I need to configure SSL on both HaProxy and Tomcat. I started with Tomcat and it works fine on port 8443. I imported the client certificate on the browser and it loads tomcat page with ssl. Then I started SSL on HaProxy and proxied this to Tomcat over SSL. Basically, I need to pass the tomcat certificate through HaProxy which is also on SSL(HaProxy(https) <-> Tomcat(https)). But always I get **503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request.** on the browser. The below is my haproxy configuration. Can anybody please help me to rectify this issue?

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 debug
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
    ssl-server-verify required
    tune.ssl.cachesize 100000
    tune.ssl.lifetime 600
    tune.ssl.maxrecord 1460
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms
    log global

frontend localhost
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/tomcat/client.pem npn http/1.1,http/1.0
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    server mybackendserver 127.0.0.1:8443 ssl verify required ca-file /etc/ssl/tomcat/ca.pem
```

Comment: Read your server logs.

Comment: This is my server logs. Apr 24 15:26:57 QB-IPL-1205 haproxy[10265]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:46598 to 127.0.0.1:443 (localhost/HTTP

Comment: try put `debug` in global section, and see the outputs, are you using self signed certs?

Comment: Hi Yes. I am using self-signed certificates.

Comment: fd[0009] OpenSSL error[0x14090086] SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: certificate verify failed
fd[0009] OpenSSL error[0x14090086] SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: certificate verify failed
fd[0009] OpenSSL error[0x14090086] SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: certificate verify failed
fd[0009] OpenSSL error[0x14090086] SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: certificate verify failed

Comment: The above is the errors I am getting on haproxy debug mode. Is this the error when trying ssl handshake on tomcat or at the nginx itself?

Comment: Seems you have an incorrect  ca  `/etc/ssl/tomcat/ca.pem`

Comment: Hi nuster, but when I load directly from tomcat it works fine. I am getting issue only when I hit through HAproxy.